# samsung omnia usb debugging

Tags: usb

can I turn on usb debugging so I can copy text messages from phone to pc? I don't know how to turn it on in the menus. Developer options isn't even listed. I can se build number but I am unable to click on it.

Comment: You are supposed to tap on the build number 7 times, and then go back in to the main settings page to find the "Developer Options" listed. However, this is an X-Y problem, @AaronGillion has answered with a solution to the base problem, so if it helps you, please accept it by clicking on the tick beside the answer.

Comment: Which particular Omnia is it? The codename?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to make a backup of your text messages, check out [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) or [SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) app in Play Store. Both of them have high reviews and don't require root.

Screenshots:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG: SMS Backup Restore]
[image: IMG: SMS Backup+]

Comment: Well, I understand this being a X-Y question and all, but should you completely avoid addressing the OP's *question* altogether?

Comment: Implying the USB debugging thing.

Comment: Multiple answers (different approaches) are encouraged here on SE, I actually wasn't sure about his USB debugging problem, so I decided to make the OP aware of the app approach that one might have not known about. I was hoping someone else better knew his model/phone to assist with the Settings panes.

Answer (score 0):

You're now recommended not to invest your time in enabling USB debugging at all, if you intend to backup or restore SMS/MMS using it. It wouldn't reap anything useful in the end.

ADB (user 2000) doesn't have adequate privilege to directly read the database *mmssms.db* located under *com.android.providers.telephony/databases* - the same database which keeps records of your received and sent SMS and MMS. Neither does it have the permission [android.permission.READ_SMS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS) to read SMS.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

So, all you can do is use an app to do the job for you, such as what Aaron [suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139866/96277) or if your vendor provides a software to manage your phone from PC, then consider trying it. It may be having the option to backup SMS and MMS.

Comment: I tested the solution on Android 6.0.1 but the information is true for quite a lot of preceding Android versions.